# Square APIs - How to order on the go Android app

Tags: java, android, e-commerce, square, square-connect

I know this is really vague but I'm looking for any sort of assistance you can offer. Basically, the vendor I am working with currently has a Point of Sale app on their iPad tablet, customers already go there and order goods on a daily basis. I am currently developing an Android app for the customers so that they can order their goods on the go, and have it ready for pick up when they arrive. Some of the documentation is a little confusing to follow, and the answer that Square customer support gave us wasn't very clear either, so I am calling on the help of fellow developers who perhaps have experience working with Square. Right now I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how users of our app would even see the menu through Square API calls, which APIs to start out with. They have lots of different ones and I'm not sure which ones are actually relevant to my task.

Here are some links I tried to look at for your reference, maybe it can help you as well:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/

https://github.com/square/connect-java-sdk

https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples

https://github.com/square/point-of-sale-android-sdk

https://github.com/square/active_merchant_square

Comment: Greetings, StackOverflow is not a tutorial service. While you did state your problem, readers won't know what are the actual project requirements which would impact any answer (making it even more opinionated). All I can recommend is review and understand all of the features listed on the left hand side of this chart: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/take-payments and get a better idea of what the vendor/your client is providing with the iPad app, perhaps by speaking with your client's developer/development team. Good luck.

Comment: Just to add on this, you're wanting to take a look at the [Catalog API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/products/catalog/overview) to be able to list their menu to the end user. The Catalog API is what allows you to view what products a Square merchant has in their account. You can find more details in the [documentation references](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-catalog).